# Why is there a type error when using List.fold_left return value?

Tags: ocaml, typeerror

I am trying to use the list returned from List.fold_left on a list of type pExp (user-defined type). The purpose of this is to create a list of Times (pExp list) with the list matched in a Plus l type.

```
let eval (lst: pExp list): pExp list = 
    match lst with
    | [] -> []
    | other patterns
    | Plus l::t -> (List.fold_left (fun acc a -> Times(a::t)::acc) lst)
    (* For each item a in l, append it to t and make it a Times *)
    | _ -> []
```

I expected List.fold_left to return a pExp list, but I get this error.

`Error: This expression has type pExp list -> pExp list
       but an expression was expected of type pExp list`

The first line in the error message indicates fold_left returns a pExp which is exactly what is expects, no?

Answer (score 3):

This expression:

```
(List.fold_left (fun acc a -> Times(a::t)::acc) lst)
```

has a function type. `List.fold_left` takes 3 arguments, and you're only passing it 2 here.

The compiler is saying that you're supplying a function type (`pExp list -> pExp list`) where a non-function type (`pExp list`) was expected. And that's indeed the problem.

Most likely you left out the initial value between the function and `lst`.